# not getting correct way of adding li elements to ul using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add `li` element to `ul` in this way

```
<li>
    <div>
        <span>Ad</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
     </div>
</li>
```

but through this code below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#notify').click(function(e) {
    $('#ul_addon').append(
      $('<li><div>').append(
        $('<span>Ad</span>'),
        $('</div>'),
        $('<div>').append(
          $('<span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>'),
          $('<span"></span>').html("New Text")
        ),
        $('</div></li>')
      )
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_addon">
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Ad</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
      <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="notify" type="button">Add</button>
```

I'm getting

```
<li>
    <div></div>
    <span>Ad</span>// this <span> is out of the <div> above
    <div>
        <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
        <span>Some text here</span>
     </div>
</li>
```

I want to have `<span>` in `<div>` element as

```
<div>
   <span>Ad</span>
</div>
```

but don't have idea of getting the desired result.

***Disclaimer :*** I'm newbie in JS world please don't mind if you find this stupid.

Comment: Looks fine to me!. Have you taken a look at console properly?

Comment: At first I was also expecting correct results, but after inspecting the `ul` element I found ___that___ weird result, please run the _code snippet_ and see the result!

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong ? I see this when I inspect!. http://imgur.com/hxNKbys

Comment: Thanks a lot! All answers may be working, but I found that accepted one useful and my job is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append div to li instead of creating div like below

```
$('<li><div>') 

// will create elements and it will look like <li><li><div></div>
```

Use the below code instead

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#notify').click(function(e) {
    $('#ul_addon').append(
      $('<li>').append(
        $('<div><span>Ad</span></div>'),

        $('<div>').append(
          $('<span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>'),
          $('<span"></span>').html("New Text")
        ),
        $('</div></li>')
      )
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_addon">
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Ad</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
      <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="notify" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! All answers may be working, but I found this useful and my job is done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how append and element creation in jQuery works. You don't need to use the end tag as a separate append. It does not work like an html string concatenation.

When you provide `$('<div>')`, it is creating the html element `<div></div>`.

When you use `$('<li><div>')`, it will create `<li><div></div></li>`, but if you chain `append()` to this, then the next append will work on the parent element, `li`. That is the reason, span is coming outside of the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#notify').click(function(e) {
    $('#ul_addon').append(
      $('<li/>').append(
        $('<div/>').append(
          $('<span>Ad</span>')
        ),
        $('<div/>').append(
          $('<span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>'),
          $('<span"></span>').html("New Text")
        )
      )
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_addon">
  <li>
    <div>
      <span>Ad</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
      <span>Some text here</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="notify" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! All answers may be working, but I found that accepted one useful and my job is done.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you must create an entire element at a time - that is to say it's opening *and* closing tag (if it has one). You cannot use jQuery to insert only a closing tag.

To fix your code it would be simpler and perform better if you just used a single append:

```
$('#notify').click(function(e){
    $('#ul_addon').append('<li><div><span>Ad</span></div><div><span><a href="#">A title.</a></span><span">New Text</span></div></li>'));
});
```

Comment: OP's code seems to just work fine. I checked in the console as well

Comment: It works in the fact that it doesn't throw an error, but if you check the HTML in the DOM inspector you'll see that it's not in the format that the OP is expecting because of the issues I state above.

Comment: @SandeepNayak If you check the added html in OP, `<span>Ad</span>`, coming out side the `div`, where it is supposed to come.

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong ? I see this when I inspect!. http://imgur.com/hxNKbys

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: My bad. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! All answers may be working, but I found that accepted one useful and my job is done.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't want to keep it simple instead of using too much `append` function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#notify').click(function(e){
        $('#ul_addon').append('<li><div><span>Ad</span></div><div><span><a href="#">A title.</a></span><span>New Text</span></div></li>')          
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_addon">    
    <li>
        <div>
            <span>Ad</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span><a href="#">A title.</a></span>
            <span>Some text here</span>
        </div>
    </li>                                            
</ul>

<button id="notify" type="button">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! All answers may be working, but I found that accepted one useful and my job is done.